# jQuery how to filter content by dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Using the Wordpress plugin Advanced Custom Fields, I have created a page to display the content of each post, as the page is very PHP heavy and relies on the database, I have simplified the code to only show the generated html.

On my page I have two dropdowns, one for the category 'Association' and 'Discipline', when selecting a dropdown, I want the post that matches the Association and/or Discipline to be displayed.

For example, if I select Association: 'Wales' then everything with Wales should display, if I then want to be more specific with the second dropdown, only show 'Wales' and 'Discipline Option 3' and if neither options are selected then all of the posts display.

Because there are so many fields I'm having a hard time trying to get this to work, what I want it to do is if the text in the `.bio-field-text` matches the option selected then all the `.card-parent` divs are hidden, only displaying the `.card-parent` divs that have the matching options.

I have very limited experience of jQuery so I've been searching for similar problems and trying their solutions to no avail.

Here is a JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sjwmzk84/1/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#association").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".bio-field-text").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".bio-field-text").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 67.5em;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row.collapse .column,
.row.collapse .columns {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: left;
}

.row .row {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: -0.9375em;
  margin-right: -0.9375em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: none;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row .row:before,
.row .row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row .row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row .row.collapse {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row .row.collapse:before,
.row .row.collapse:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row .row.collapse:after {
  clear: both;
}

.column,
.columns {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.9375em;
  padding-right: 0.9375em;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen {
  .column,
  .columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375em;
    padding-right: 0.9375em;
    float: left;
  }
  .small-5 {
    position: relative;
    width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .small-7 {
    position: relative;
    width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .small-12 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  [class*="column"]+[class*="column"]:last-child {
    float: right;
  }
  [class*="column"]+[class*="column"].end {
    float: left;
  }
}


/* Styles for screens that are atleast 768px; */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.4.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="categoryfilter" id="association" data-tableId="card-parent">
  <option>Association</option>
  <option>Kent</option>
  <option>Wales</option>
  <option>Stafford</option>
</select>

<select name="categoryfilter" id="discipline" data-tableId="card-parent">>
  <option>Discipline</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 1</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 2</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 3</option>
</select>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    John &amp; Peanuts </h1>

  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Peanuts </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Pitbull </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          10 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          John </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Stafford </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 1 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    Alex &amp; Ben </h1>
  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Ben </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Labrador </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          12 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Alex </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Kent </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 2 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    Kyle &amp; Nougat </h1>
  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Nougat </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Hound </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          7 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Kyle </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Wales </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery librairy filtering and sortering. Maybe it's what you need. This one is great : https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a little with your code, here is a working snippet:
(I only modified JS, it's rather short. See comments.)

```js
$("#association, #discipline").change(function() {
  var associationOpt = $("#association").find("option:selected").text(); // Gets selected value for association
  var disciplineOpt = $("#discipline").find("option:selected").text(); // Gets selected value for discipline
  $(".card-parent").show(); // Shows all cards
  $(".card-parent").each(function(index) { // Then, for each card…
    if (!($(this).text().includes(associationOpt) && $(this).text().includes(disciplineOpt))) {
      $(this).hide(); // … hides if one of the selected options isn't found
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 67.5em;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row.collapse .column,
.row.collapse .columns {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: left;
}

.row .row {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: -0.9375em;
  margin-right: -0.9375em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: none;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row .row:before,
.row .row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row .row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row .row.collapse {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row .row.collapse:before,
.row .row.collapse:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row .row.collapse:after {
  clear: both;
}

.column,
.columns {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.9375em;
  padding-right: 0.9375em;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen {
  .column,
  .columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375em;
    padding-right: 0.9375em;
    float: left;
  }
  .small-5 {
    position: relative;
    width: 41.66667%;
  }
  .small-7 {
    position: relative;
    width: 58.33333%;
  }
  .small-12 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  [class*="column"]+[class*="column"]:last-child {
    float: right;
  }
  [class*="column"]+[class*="column"].end {
    float: left;
  }
}


/* Styles for screens that are atleast 768px; */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.4.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="categoryfilter" id="association" data-tableId="card-parent">
  <option>Association</option>
  <option>Kent</option>
  <option>Wales</option>
  <option>Stafford</option>
</select>

<select name="categoryfilter" id="discipline" data-tableId="card-parent">>
  <option>Discipline</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 1</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 2</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 3</option>
</select>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    John &amp; Peanuts </h1>

  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Peanuts </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Pitbull </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          10 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          John </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Stafford </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 1 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    Alex &amp; Ben </h1>
  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Ben </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Labrador </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          12 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Alex </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Kent </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 2 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    Kyle &amp; Nougat </h1>
  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Nougat </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Hound </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          7 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Kyle </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Wales </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working exactly what I wanted! And appears so short and simple, you wouldn't believe the hours I've spent trying to figure this out, you've made me very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the class `.bio-field-text` on a lot of elements that aren't in the select dropdown, this is going to be rather difficult if you don't add a class to the ones that are potential matches. For simplicity's sake, I've added a class called `.option` and pulled out the white space in the `<p>` tags.

HTML

```
<select name="categoryfilter" id="association" data-tableId="card-parent">
  <option>Association</option>
  <option>Kent</option>
  <option>Wales</option>
  <option>Stafford</option>
</select>

<select name="categoryfilter" id="discipline" data-tableId="card-parent">>
  <option>Discipline</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 1</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 2</option>
  <option>Discipline Choice 3</option>
</select>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    John &amp; Peanuts </h1>

  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Peanuts </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Pitbull </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          10 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          John </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text select">Stafford</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 1 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
   Alex &amp; Ben </h1>
  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Ben </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Labrador </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          12 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Alex </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text select">Kent</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 2 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-parent">
  <h1 class="bio-card-title">
    Kyle &amp; Nougat </h1>
  <div class="small-12 column biography-card-text">
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's name: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Nougat </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Breed: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Hound </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Dog's age: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          7 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Handler: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Kyle </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Association: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text select">Wales</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bio-card-row">
      <div class="small-5 column">
        <p class="bio-field-title">
          Discipline: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column">
        <p class="bio-field-text">
          Discipline Choice 3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column bio-card-btm-content">
      <p>Example text</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You also want to make sure jQuery is working. The fiddle didn't have it turned on. Then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#association").on('change', function (){

    var optionValue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

    $(".select").each(function(){
      if ($(this).text() !== optionValue){
        $(this).parents('.card-parent').hide();
      }
      else {
        $(this).parents('.card-parent').show();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjwmzk84/3/